# How to bridge throwable Swift initialiser with Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling, initialization, bridge

Let's say we have a Swift class with an initializer which can throw an error. This class must be used in `Objective-C` codebase (`NSObject` subclass):

```
import Foundation

enum EvenError : ErrorType {
    case NonEvenNumber
}

class FooEven : NSObject {
    var evenNumber : UInt

    init(evenNumber: UInt) throws {
        guard evenNumber % 2 == 0 else {
            throw EvenError.NonEvenNumber
        }
        self.evenNumber = evenNumber
    }
}
```

Produces compilation warning:

```
<unknown>:0: warning: no calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression
```

I can work around this warning in 2 ways:

- by replacing throwable initialiser (`init... -> throws`) with failable one (`init?`)
- giving up on subclassing from `NSObject`

Yet this way I will:

- loose information about an error causing the exception,
- have to make instances of FooEven optionals and / or handle many: `if let fooEven = FooEven.init() {...}` statements
- ... or I will not be able to use it in existing `Objective-C` code:

[image]

None of the above satisfies my needs / requirements.

Is there an other way to remove that warning without loosing information about the error?

Comment: Can you use a closure that contains an NSError object to capture the error info?  I don't know that much about Swift, sorry.

Comment: Don't have an answer for you, but did you ever resolve this? Running into the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to add a throwing convenience initializer that calls your non-throwing designated initializer.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a bug in the Swift compiler](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1611) and is fixed in Xcode 8.  When you upgrade Xcode, this warning will go away.

In the meantime, you can call `super.init()` at the end of your initialiser and this will also make the warning go away.